# Problemas de estructuracion de datos

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, método

les comento tengo el siguiente problema tengo este código dentro de mi pagina principal:

```
<?php 
  $var = $_GET['pagina'];
  if(!$_GET){
    header('location:doc.php?pagina=1');
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

...Contenido de la pagina...

<div id="tabla_resultado">
    <!-- AQUI SE DESPLEGA LA TABLA DE CONSULTA -->
</div>
</section>
<script>
    var variable = <?php echo $var; ?>;
    $(obtener_registros());

    function obtener_registros(clientes){

        $.ajax({
            url : 'consult.php',
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'html',
            data :  { variable: variable, clientes: clientes},
        })

        .done(function(resultado){
            $("#tabla_resultado").html(resultado);
        });
    }

    $(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
        var valorBusqueda=$('#search').val();
        if (valorBusqueda!=""){
            obtener_registros(valorBusqueda);
        }
        else{
            obtener_registros();
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

me funciona todo correcto sin ningun problema, todo el codigo funciona, pero si intento separarlo para obtener cada elemento en su respectivo archivo de la siguiente manera:

pagina principal:

```
<?php 
  $var = $_GET['pagina'];
  if(!$_GET){
    header('location:doc.php?pagina=1');
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

...Contenido de la pagina...

<div id="tabla_resultado">
    <!-- AQUI SE DESPLEGA LA TABLA DE CONSULTA -->
</div>
</section>
<script>
    var variable = <?php echo $var; ?>;
</script>
```

javascript.js:

```
$(obtener_registros());

function obtener_registros(clientes){

    $.ajax({
        url : 'consult.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'html',
        data :  { variable: variable, clientes: clientes},
    })

    .done(function(resultado){
            $("#tabla_resultado").html(resultado);
    });
    }

$(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
    var valorBusqueda=$('#search').val();
    if (valorBusqueda!=""){
        obtener_registros(valorBusqueda);
    }
    else{
        obtener_registros();
    }
});
```

De esta manera no se me ejecuta el código, a que se puede deber que estoy haciendo mal o por que mi código no se ejecuta de la misma manera como la hace cuando esta dentro del documento principal?

Comment: en tu archivo HTML, no veo en ningún momento que en la etiqueta `script` invoques a tu archivo .js

Comment: si la estoy llamando de la siguiente manera solo que para cuestiones de no saturar la pregunta solo puse lo que me da problemas. la tengo de esta manera `<script src="js/javascript.js"></script>` y la ubicacion es correcta, todo esta bien en mi documento de la manera que menciono primero pero al tratar de separarlos es cuando no me funciona.

Comment: abre la consola de desarrollador del navegador y cuando cargas la página que error te da?

Comment: en la consola del navegador me dice **ReferenceError: variable is not defined**, pero si creeo un boton que llame la funcion `function obtener_registros(){` si me muestra los resultados a que se debe o como le puedo hacer para migrar la variable de forma correcta desde mi archivo principal al javascript.js ?

Comment: tenes que asegurarte que el tag que carga el js esté despues de `var variable = <?php echo $var; ?>;`